How should I solve this text alignment problem in my web design?
I'm currently building a new website in wix for my company, and I wanted to know if it's a graphic/UI sin to have mismatching headlines with a single line sentence vs double. The website is responsive with multiple breakpoints.
Assuming I can't change the width of these blocks for the breakpoint, should I decrease the font size or turn on a scale option to keep everything on a single line? Would it be fine to just have the text be aligned with the top line of each header when any of the text wraps depending on the screen size?


Change the first heading so it's also two words and always have them in two lines?

I'd do what @Wolff suggests .. "Budgeting and Stability" and remove "Supporting your" from the subtext so it's merely 1 line. Or perhaps "Your financial stability — current and long-term." Or add more to the other subtexts so they are all 2 lines. I often use responsive break tags so things break at large in order to match how they naturally break when small.

Alternatively, just improve your whitespace in the current view. It looks like there's an inconsistent amount of whitespace around the different image subjects. The space between the heading and the description is too large compared to the line height of the description. You might also increase the amount of padding that the container has

With UI like this, it's often not great practice to assume that the copy that you currently have will always be the copy. It could be translated, new entries could be added, or the copy just changed later. Not to mention these containers may change in width depending on the viewport. So it's better practice to try and get it working no matter the text

Although this is very taste depended.
There are a few things that track my attention.
The different scales of the images, the lady looks small.
Also the use creditcards, it depends coins or paper money, oh well it's new age.
Though those 3 images look as if made by 3 different artist.
Center image okay, first image, add white border around cards adding contrast, the lady is just small and unrelated (a hand holding a bag of coins maybe)..
Better have a fixed height after which below the text is shown.
Don't let text dance, the same counts for the smaller text.
It's just more slick if things are well placed.
The word choices themselves maybe rethink it.

Budgetering, Retering, Investing
Budgetering, Retirements, Investments.

or add equal wordings as control, services, management, administration:

Budget control, Retirement control, investment control.

Notice though that i'm not a native English speaker/writer.
Though in my language i would solve it in such ways.
